# Adding a fragment?

Tags: java, android, xml, string, algorithm

I am using this library:

https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/AppIntro

To create a tutorial for my application. Now, I want to add a fragment as a slide. How can I do that? I tried this:

```
    addSlide(R.layout.fragment_first);
```

My fragment layout is `fragment_first.xml`, and I just want to add it. I think the parameter only accepts a fragment id...How can I add that to my fragment layout xml?

[image]

How can I add the fragment as a slide?

Thanks,

Ruchir

Comment: Create a new instance of the Fragment that inflates that layout, and pass that to the addSlide() method

Comment: @DanielNugent I tried that, but it didn't work. `Fragment fragment = new Fragment(R.layout.fragment_first);`. This didn't work. How should I do it? Feel free to post an answer too! :)

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**

Note that the `addSlide()` method takes a `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` as a parameter.

Assuming you have a FirstFragment.java that looks something like this:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {


    public FirstFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
    }

}
```

Just create a new instance of FirstFragment, and pass it to the `addSlide()` method:

```
FirstFragment fragment = new FirstFragment();
addSlide(fragment);
```

**Option 2**

Looking at the Readme:

> - Copy the class SampleSlide from my [example project](https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/AppIntro/blob/master/example/src/main/java/com/github/paolorotolo/appintroexample/SampleSlide.java).
> - Add a new slide with    `addSlide(SampleSlide.newInstance(R.layout.your_slide_here));`

So, for you it would be:

```
addSlide(SampleSlide.newInstance(R.layout.fragment_first));
```